# Effect of array1.concat(array2) not persisting after function call

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, concatenation

this works:

```
var f = function(a){
   a.push(1);
};
var a = [];
f(a);
console.log(a);//[1];
```

But this:

```
var f = function(a){
   a = a.concat([1]);
};
var a = [];
f(a);
console.log(a);//[];
```

Does not work. With work I mean that the changes made persist after the function call.

Now I realise that this most likely has something to do with the arguments being passed 'as reference by value', meaning that a change in reference (ie assigning a new object) does not persist after the function call.

So I wonder, is there a persistent version of concat? Or do I manualy have to push all elements from one array into the other?

Edit: All of you suggesting to return the newly created array: that's pretty much exactly what I don't want. If I wanted to do that I wouldn't have created this question. And I certainly would not have ended it specifically asking for a persistent version of concat.

Comment: -1: If you had bothered to read up on [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), you wont be asking this question.

Comment: @AlvinK. Actually I mentioned that I realise that concat creates a new object, so that I'm not suprised by this behaviour. I'm just wondering if there is a slightly different version of concat available that I'm not aware of. -1 cause if you had bothered to read my question you wouldn't be commenting that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the function parameter, `a`, is not the same as the variable `a` declared in the outer scope. When you assign a new value to the parameter `a`, it has no effect on the outer variable.

```
a = a.concat([1]);
```

Instead, simply return the new array, and use the return value in the outer scope, like this:

```
var f = function(a){
   return a.concat([1]);
};
var a = [];
a = f(a);
```

Or perhaps consider using `push` like this:

```
var f = function(a){
   Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [1, 2, 3]);
};
```

This will push multiple values onto the source array, so it's pretty much equivalent to `concat` except that it modifies the original array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the apply push method than

Answer (score 3):

`concat` returns a new array, it doesn't mutate the source array.

```
var f = function(a){
   return a.concat([1]);
};

var a = f([]);

console.log(a);//[1];
```

If you do want to mutate the array, just use `push.apply` to pass array elements as individual arguments to the `push` function.

```
 var f = function(a) {
     a.push.apply(a, [1]);
 };

 var a = [];

 f(a);

 console.log(a); //1
```

Comment: @user2520938 Note that you do not have to use `Array.prototype.push.apply` like in the other answer ;)